# in web.xml i have data initparam i mean in context object i need to get this context object to get data in soap

Tags: java, soap

in web.xml i have data initparam i mean in context object i need to get this context object to get data in soap

```
@WebService

@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)

public interface serviceInterface {

    @WebMethod

    public return method(parameter ....);
}


@WebService(endpointInterface="com.servion.service.SmsserviceInterface")

public class Service implements serviceInterface {


    @Override

    public return method(parameter ....){

}

}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Servlet Context is available by JAX-WS via the message context.

Create class member variable of WebServiceContext and define @Resource annotation with it:

@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;

Then, you can access the servlet context in class using:

ServletContext servletContext =
    (ServletContext) context.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);